# Parsing JSON doubts - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to parse this JSOn with multiple entries of "node" tag:

```
{
   "nodes": [
      {
         "node": {
            "title": "Jornada del Fútbol Profesional contra el hambre",
            "description": "
             "image": ",
            "fecha": ,
            "nid": ",
            "noticia_relacionada_1_path": ,
            "noticia_relacionada_2_path": ,
            "image_small_2": 
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is the code:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
    //data =nil;

    NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];  

    NSArray *noticias = [results objectForKey:@"node"];

    self.noticiasArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [noticias count]; i++) {

        news *noticia = [[news alloc] initWithDictionary:[noticias objectAtIndex:i]]; 
        [self.noticiasArray addObject:noticia]; 
        noticia=nil;

    }
```

I got 10 elements in the notices array, but when I try to get the inner values in the initWithDictionary: they are always null.

Many thanks

Comment: This "JSON" is broken.  What's with the lonely quotes?

Comment: Debug it.  My guess is that you're getting a dictionary with one "node" element as the "initWithDictionary" parm.  You're probably expecting to see the "title", et al, elements directly, but there's one more layer of the onion to unpeel.

Comment: How can I get to the inner tags? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
//data =nil;

NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];  

NSDictionary *noticias = [results objectForKey:@"node"];

news *noticia = [[news alloc] init];
noticia.title = [noticias objectForKey:@"title"]; 
// do the same for the rest of the variables
[self.noticiasArray addObject:noticia]; 
noticia=nil;
```